projectile not showing files under a .git directory
I had a directory structure like this:
.projectile
lots of folders
onefolder/nested/.git
onefolder/bunch of other stuff

when locked into the top-level project, none of the files under the .git directory show up, but i wanted them to. i deleted the .git to test, and now it starts detecting them. is there some way around this, to get it to recognize all under as part of the project, or maybe also ignore some?
i even added a .projectile to the directory with the .git, and it didn't recognize it as even its own project.

projectile doesn't really play well with sub-projects or nested projects. maybe you can try the work-around in this issue: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1130#issuecomment-1123237339
